# 'NoneType' object is not an iterator for python progressbar library

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate a large panda dataframe with progressbar to show the progress. 
However, I have encountered multiple error when trying to iterate with the progressbar.

My code is as follows:

```
import progressbar
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 5, np.nan, 6, 8])

for index, item in progressbar.ProgressBar(test.iterrows()):
    print(index)
    print(item)
```

The error that was output is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-797fb77c4b2d> in <module>
----> 1 for index, item in progressbar.ProgressBar(test.iterrows()):
      2     print(index)
      3     print(item)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\progressbar\progressbar.py in __next__(self)
    148     def __next__(self):
    149         try:
--> 150             value = next(self.__iterable)
    151             if self.start_time is None:
    152                 self.start()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator
```

I have tried multiple versions of the code, but still encountered different errors:

```
for index, item in progressbar.ProgressBar(test):
    print(index)
    print(item)
```

With error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9aa55b0f5d38> in <module>
----> 1 for index, item in progressbar.ProgressBar(test):
      2     print(index)
      3     print(item)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\progressbar\progressbar.py in __next__(self)
    148     def __next__(self):
    149         try:
--> 150             value = next(self.__iterable)
    151             if self.start_time is None:
    152                 self.start()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator
```

While:

```
for index, item in progressbar(test.iterrows()):
    print(index)
    print(item)
```

Results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-8d9ab3e17978> in <module>
----> 1 for index, item in progressbar(test.iterrows()):
      2     print(index)
      3     print(item)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am stuck in this part for a while now, trying different combination of the code to obtain the progress bar.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank You.

Comment: You have `np.nan` in your data frame. You need to remove it for the progress bar to work properly.

Comment: Um... I don't think this is the problem, since I encountered the same error with np.nan removed.

Answer (score 0):

`progressbar.ProgressBar(test.iterrows())` doesn't return an object that can be iterated. ACtually it returns `None`, the errors tells you that pretty clearly. I don't know Panda but to me it looks like you are trying to iterate over `test.iterrows()` and that probably will give you `index` and `item`?

try this:

```
for whatever in test.iterrows():
    print(whatever)
```

see what it gives you.

As for how to use progressbar, I'm not sure, since I'm not a Panda user but if I have to guess, `progressbar.Progressbar()` will create a progressbar object and then probably you have to assign min and max and the actual value in the loop... At least this what I would expect from a UI framework like, for example, Qt.

Comment: I can successfully iterate and output the index and item in the for loop with your code. But I want to add a progressbar to show my progress since for my read dataframe, there are over 100000 items. Using progressbar, I can know the my current progress.

Comment: I just told you why you have the error. As I'm not a data scientist and no my main focus when using python, I cannot give you a final solution, BUT knowing WHY you get that error is important to figure out what you are doing wrong... don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to iterate over Panda's dataframe:

```
for item in progressbar.progressbar(test.iterrows(), max_value=test.shape[0]):
    print(item)
```

Explanation:

- `progressbar.progressbar` returns only the item and not the `index, item` pair as returned by generator from `test.iterrows()`
- to enable the right output, you need to specify the number of rows in your dataframe as this library does not inherently understand panda's DF. So, we need to pass `max_value=test.shape[0]` where `test.shape[0]` gives the number of rows you have in the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Using ProgressBar might lead to some issues in this scenario. I would recommend instead to use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) which is way faster and supports Pandas.

Here's a working solution:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tqdm.pandas()

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 5, np.nan, 6, 8])
df.progress_apply(print)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# initializing progressbar
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()

# setting iterable value to the bar by calling __call__ method
bar(test.iterrows())

for index, item in enumerate(bar):
    print(index, item)
```

You can check out the [source code](https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar/blob/master/progressbar/progressbar.py) of the Progressbar. There is some example that you can try.